# javascript print function not working on EMBED tag in IE 10, IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

ASPX

```
if (tdclosetxt.innerHTML.indexOf("<A title=\"Download Adobe Reader\"") == -1) {
    tdclosetxt.innerHTML = "<a target='_blank' href='http://get.adobe.com/reader' title='Download Adobe Reader' ><img src='../inc/img/AdobeLogo.ico' /></a>" + tdclosetxt.innerHTML
}
tdPrint.innerHTML = "<embed id='empdf' src ='" + ExcelURL + "' width='0' height='0'>Click <a href='#' onclick='PrintPdf()' > here </a> to Print.";
```

Clicking on the link calls this JavaScript function:

```
function PrintPdf() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById('empdf');
    x.click();
    x.setActive();
    x.focus();
    x.print();
}
```

The above code works fine in IE 8 and 9, but when my client upgrades to IE 10 or 11 the print popup is hanged. Please guide me

Comment: @SaggingRufus Recent IE versions are fine, no need to exaggerate.

Comment: @Stijn yup. its works fine in IE 8,9 but in IE 10 the print popup got hanging.

Comment: @SaggingRufus All fate still client using IE. instead fighting with IE bugs we can install chrome to all client system.

Comment: I realize a lot of people use IE thats why I suggested searching up Jscript because that it is what IE uses instead of JavaScript. Through they are very similar, they are not the same and that could be the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. It started when the user upgraded to IE 10. He is still using Adobe Acrobat 9, and it was the default program rendering PDFs in the browser. I downloaded Adobe Reader XI and made it the default program for rendering PDFs in the browser. He can now print. Problem solved.